# Fill part of a LaTeX page with colour?

Tags: color

With `\pagecolor` you can change the colour of the entire page.  However I'm trying to create a style which has a fixed-width white band at the top of the page and a solid fill colour for the rest of the paper.  The colour should extend margin to margin.

I've been trying to achieve this using `\colorbox` around a minipage environment but am having trouble getting the minipage to automatically resize vertically.

Here's a MWE and example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in,top=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

% move box to leftmost edge of paper
\noindent\hspace*{-1in}%
\colorbox{red}{\begin{minipage}{\paperwidth}%
    % Start text back at original margin
    \hspace*{1in}
    \color{white}
    \Huge Hello!

    % Fill to bottom of page? Not working
    \vspace*{\fill}\mbox{}
  \end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Red fill should go all the way to bottom of page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following examples uses [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to insert a `red` block in the `B`ack`G`round of every page. The red block spans the width of the entire page horizontally, and covers everything but the top `2in` vertically:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in,top=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \color{red}%
    \rule{\pdfpagewidth}{\dimexpr\pdfpageheight-2in}%
  }
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\color{white}% Set text colour
\Huge\bfseries Hello!

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't say but I needed this for the first page only; easily achieved with `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{...}`.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[red] ($(current page.north west)-(0cm,3cm)$) rectangle (current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\color{white}\Huge\bfseries Hello!
\end{document}
```